# Vue js v-for and css nth-child

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

v-for seems to mess up element index. i have the following code:

```
<style>
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
 .grid:nth-child(2) {
 clear: left;
 background-color: gray; 
 border: 1px solid yellow; 
 }
}
</style>
```

then in my code:

```
<div v-for="n in posts">
 <div class="grid">{{n}}</div>
</div>
```

here child 2 doesn't exists. CSS styles only applied if child 1 is specified.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: jsfiddle or plunker would be helpful to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`.grid:nth-child(2)` means every `.grid` element that is the second child of its parent. But since your `v-for` is on the containing `div` it's actually creating a container around each `.grid` so there are no `.grid` elements that are second children.  I think you probably actually want the `v-for` on the `.grid` element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.grid:nth-child(2) {
 clear: left;
 background-color: gray; 
 border: 1px solid yellow; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="grid"  v-for="n in posts">{{n}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @IsmailS if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.